# I want to store this in redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, node-redis

I want to store an array of objects in redis

```js
const items = [
  {
    '122': {
      name: 'abc',
      price: '12',
    },
  },
  {
    '1225656': {
      name: 'bc',
      price: '35',
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: Go ahead and proceed to store it..

Comment: `redis_client.set (property , JSON.stringify( object  ), `
            `function (err, redisData) {`
                `console.log("something went wrong ", err, redisData) });`

Answer (score 1):

if you were to use string data type, this is how you do it

```js
// set it
await redis.set('keyname', JSON.stringify(items))

// get it back

const dataStr = await redis.get('keyname')
const data = JSON.parse(dataStr)
```

of course you can use other data type like hash (or storing list items) and list (item keys) all together. but if the json payload is small, I think you will be just fine using string.